# What is the category of compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous functions?

Tags: category-theory

Page 9 of the textbook "Categories for the Working Mathematician" gives as examples of metacategories: "All topological spaces with continuous functions as arrows, all compact Hausdorff spaces with the same as arrows".

By 'the same' here it seems to mean continuous functions, same as the arrows of the topological space. But if so, the second example seems trivial. The compact Hausdorff spaces are simply a subset of the topological spaces, and continuous functions between them are simply a subset-restriction of the same categorical structure as the prior example of topological spaces. One could take any metacategory and restrict objects and arrows to a subset of objects, so it doesn't seem that this compact Hausdorff example bears mentioning. Yet somehow the specific 'compact Hausdorff' qualifier was somehow selected.

Is my understanding correct, that this example is trivial after the example of topological spaces with continuous functions was stated immediately before? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a full subcategory of that of topological spaces; but is is a very nice subcategory...

Comment: The category of abelian groups is a full subcategory of the category of groups, but that doesn't make it "trivial" or uninteresting. The category of abelian groups also has very different properties than the category of groups. One important idea that category theory emphasizes is that we can study objects by studying how they relate to other objects. As a consequence, if we restrict to a subclass of objects to relate to then the properties we see change.